# Get Specific Values from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to Mongo so any help is appreciated.

I have a User object and in it multiple more objects which are hosting client data based on the User's interaction with each one.

This is how it looks like

```js
db.users.findOne(
  {"clients.clientId":35},
  {"clients.clientId":1}
)
```

```json
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("586670e6ce9287cf6d197d14"),
  "clients" : [ 
        { "clientId" : 35 },
        { "clientId" : 67 }, 
        { "clientId" : 73 }, 
        { "clientId" : 78 }, 
        { "clientId" : 82 } 
  ] 
}
```

As you can see from my query, it returns a User that has data from client 35 but also returns data from every other client.

How can I access only the data from client 35?

Comment: Try this `db.users.findOne({"clients.clientId":35},{"clients.$":1})`

Comment: @SagarReddy can you please explain a bit what you suggested? what is clients.$ ?

Comment: docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional‌​. The query part identifies the row and project part uses $positional operator to display the matched value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an embedded array of documents on the `clients` key.

Your query projection `{"clients.clientId":1}` states that the query should return only that key, `clients` key.  Your `clients` field is an array, therefore all embedded documents from the array will be extracted (projected).

When you want only one element in the array to be displayed, the one defined in the query i.e. the client with id 35 `{"clients.clientId":35}`, need to use the [projection positional operator $](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/projection/positional/):

```
db.users.findOne({"clients.clientId":35},{"clients.$":1})
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("586670e6ce9287cf6d197d14"),
    "clients" : [
        {
            "clientId" : 35
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: using `$` operator, it will project only the **first** element in the array that matches the query; if you have more documents in the array having the same value, only the first will be displayed.

Comment: I do have everything related to client 35 under the same document. That would be ok right?